# CORS error xmlhttprequest no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource in Angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, nginx, cors, aws-api-gateway, nssm

An Angularjs app is using a new connection to an AWS API GW service on a different domain. CORS has been enabled but am still getting error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/api1' from origin
> 'https://angularapp.host' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

It fails before this:

```
return $http.get(AWS_API_GW_Server, headers).then(function (res) {
```

I tried configuring CORS in the nssm/nginx config also but still have same issue.  Only way I could resolve it was by creating a new Chrome shortcut as follows:

> "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
> --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=C:/temp

How can I fix this properly in either Angularjs app or NGinx?

Angularjs snippets

```
.run(function ($rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    var authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles;
    //console.log('routeChangeStart: ' + authorizedRoles);
    if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
      var auth = AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles);
      event.preventDefault();
      if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
        // user is not allowed
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
      } else {
        // user is not logged in
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Auth service login function

```
authService.login = function (credentials) {
    var base64Token = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(credentials.userName + ':' + credentials.password));
    var headers = { headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic '+ base64Token} };

    return $http.get(AuthenticationServer, headers)
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log("response isAuthenticated: " + res.data.isAuthenticated);
        var userRole = ""
        if (res.data.isAuthenticated == 'true') {
          var memberOfList = res.data.memberOf
          var groupa= "removed"
          var groupb= "removed"

          if(memberOfList.includes(groupa) || memberOfList.includes(groupb)) {
            userRole = USER_ROLES.admin
            Session.create(credentials.userName, USER_ROLES.admin);
          } else {
            userRole = USER_ROLES.guest
            Session.create(credentials.userName, USER_ROLES.guest);
          }

          return { user: res.data.fullName, auth : true, role : userRole};
        } else {
          return { user: credentials.userName, auth : false, role : userRole };
        }
      })
  };
```

Nginx config snippet

```
server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  localhost;

  ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

  ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

  root   D:/apppath/app;
  index  index.html /app/index.html;

  location / {
    
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin"; # DO NOT remove THIS LINES (doubled with outside 'if' above)
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000; # cache preflight value for 20 days
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        return 204;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

**UPDATE** - network tab info

preflight OPTIONS request appears to be successful and has been enabled on the AWS API GW resource.
[image]

Response headers from OPTIONS call appear OK too
[image]

Regardless, the actual service call throws a CORS error, presumably because the Host (AWS target API) and Origin headers are different.  With chrome hack above this works so issue appears to be browser based but can't see how else to override this.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'AWS target endpoint' from origin 'Where
> Angularjs UI is based' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Comment: Great, question looks OK now.

Comment: Have you looked at your network panel in a browser to see if the client is making an OPTIONS call? What can you tell us about the request or the response? I think this is how the client determines the CORS status.

Comment: thanks halfer, i've updated the post with additional network panel info.  looks like OPTIONS call works fine with 200 OK but then the actual XMLHttpRequest still fails, am guessing due to Host and Origin being different values.

Comment: I notice the preflight call is on port 8080, I wonder if that is what the issue is (I assume they both use TLS). Might there be another CORS header to send if the app & AJAX endpoint use different ports?